# Addition (+) does not want to run in if/else

Tags: c, loops, math

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        char values[2];
        scanf("%c", &values[0]);
        scanf("%d", &values[1]);
        if (values[0] == '*')
        {
            a = a * values[1];
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        }
        else if (values[0] == '+')
        {
            a = a + values[1];
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        }
        else if (values[0] == '%')
        {
            a = a % values[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

When I input `5 + 3 + 7 + 10 + 2 + 3 + 1 % 11`, it would show `5` (because `5%11 = 5`). But the `+` operation didn't work. Can you see what is the problem here?

Comment: `"%c"` --> `" %c"`

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try it

Comment: Writing to `values[1]` as if it has 4 bytes will break something.

Comment: Do you compile with warnings enabled? I got warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'char *'

Comment: `scanf("%d", &values[1]);` is wrong as well. What is `%d` reading? What is `values[1]`? Perhaps you wanted something like `int values[2]` outside the loop, and then `char a` inside for the operator?

Comment: I think what he is trying to do is that, at first he will give a number in `a` and then he will give one `char` type and one `int` type variable, and will proceed the task according to char type variable with his first value `a` with the `int` type value. `a` will change after every operation, and finally when he will get the `%` operator then after doing that operation he will break the loop and outside the loop he will print the current value of `a`

Comment: @SahadatHossain yes, that is excatly what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Riszky hermawan i have given my answer, have look, that will solve your problem, i hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as `values[2]` is only two variable you need, you can use two different variable to do your job. use one `char` type variable and one `int` type variable as you need these two. You have another problem in your code, use a `getchar()` in the inside of the loop then your code will work fine, cause when you give a integer value as input then take a character value last you enter the new line that goes to that character that is why your code was giving error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        getchar();
        char ch;
        int value;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        scanf("%d", &value);

        if (ch == '*')
        {
            a = a * value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        }
        else if (ch == '+')
        {
            a = a + value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        }
        else if (ch == '%')
        {
            a = a % value;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    printf("%d", a);   
}
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65762564/addition-does-not-want-to-run-in-if-else#comment116271771_65762564)

Comment: Thank you, it works! But  what is excatly getchar() does?

Comment: getchar is a function that reads a single character from the standard input stream stdin, regardless of what it is. Basically when you take input `a` in outside the loop and also the `value` inside the loop then you press the enter, because of that `\n` goes to charater variable, to avoid this basically used getchar.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- `value` is an array of `char`: scanning the operator into a `char` is fine, but the value should be converted into an `int` variable.
- the `scanf("%c", ...)` will store the next byte into the variable, but after converting an `int`, the next byte is the pending space or newline, not the `'+'`. You should use `scanf(" %c", ...)` to skip the whitespace after the previous conversion.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        char op;
        int value;
        if (scanf(" %c", &op) != 1)
            break;
        if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
            break;

        if (op == '*') {
            a = a * value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        } else
        if (op == '+') {
            a = a + value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        } else
        if (op == '-') {
            a = a - value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        } else
        if (op == '%') {
            a = a % value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        } else
        if (op == '/') {
            a = a / value;
            printf(" = %d\n", a);
        } else {
            printf("invalid operator %c\n", op);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```